# Comparing the asymptotic growth of certain functions.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Consider some nonconstant functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and suppose $\lim_ {x \to a} f(x) > \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ for some nonzero $a$.

Can we *somehow* conclude that $f(x) - g(x)$ is of constant sign for sufficiently large $x$ ?

Comment: If you mean for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$, yes.

Comment: @Augastin, i mean as $x$ tends to $+\infty$

Comment: But you wrote $x\to a$. $a=+\infty$ then?

Comment: @Augastin, no i just mean that $f$ and $g$ approach different limits at some $ a$ in the domain of $x$. What the question requires is can we then conclude that $f(x) - g(x)$ is of constant sign given *this* information.

Comment: If $a$ is a real number, the fact that $f$ and $g$ have different limits at $a$ does not imply anything about $f$ and $g$ asymptotically.

Comment: @5xum, i'm not sure if your edit is quite what i meant.

Comment: @User1 Well, you said "I mean as $x$ tends to $\infty$", so I understood that was what you meant.

Comment: @Augastin, that's why i asked that *can we somehow*.

Comment: @User1 Based on your current question, I added an answer. Can you comment on it (did I misunderstand something or does it answer your question?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can say about what happens at $x\to\infty$ just from knowing that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)>\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$.

For example, take $f(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)\sin x$ and $a=0$. You have $1=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)>\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 2$, but the sign of $f(x)-g(x)$ changes all the time.

Comment: Okay thank you, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that there exists an open interval $I$ centred in $a$ such that $f(x) - g(x)$ is strictly positive for every $x \in I$. This follows by the definition of limit.

We can't say anything about the behaviour of the two functions at $+\infty$ (I assume that $a \in \mathbb{R}$).  For example take $f(x) = 0$, $g(x) = \sin(x)$ and $a = \frac{3\pi}{2}$.

EDIT: If you meant $a = +\infty$, then you can say that there is a $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) - g(x)>0$ for every $x >K$. This follows directly from the definition of limit.